# Visual Studio - Android emulator will run unaccelerated when starting Maui Blazor app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, maui

Windows 10 x-64, all latest updates. I just upgraded Visual Studio 2022 Community to 17.3.0, which includes Maui.

Following the [instructions on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration), I enabled hardware virtualisation in the BIOS, then enabled Hyper-V in Windows Features...

[image]

...and then rebooted.

I created a new Maui app, and following the instructions in the "Build and run the application on Android" section of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/build-mobile-and-desktop-apps/4-exercise-create-your-first-maui-app), created an Android device. I have since double-checked, and it is using the x86_64 processor.

However, when I tried to run the app in the Android emulator, I got the following warning...

[image: Visual Studio warning - Android emulator will run unaccelerated]

According to the hardware virtualisation page I linked above, I should be able to accelerate the hardware using an AMD Ryzen processor. I ran [the emulator check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows), and also ran `systeminfo` from a command prompt, which gave the following (two outputs combined into one image)...

[image]

Whilst the Hyper-V requirements look fine, I'm puzzled why the emulator output says that Hyper-V is not installed. As you can see from the Windows Features screenshot, and the output from `systeminfo` it seems it is.

My PC has an Aorus X570 Elite motherboard, with an AMD Ryzen 9 3900X processor. As far as I can see from searching, this should be fine for this.

Anyone able to help? I'm brand new at virtualisation, acceleration and emulators, so might be doing something basic wrong here.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Did you try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows#hyper-v-issues

Comment: Thanks, but the Powershell command shows Hyper-V is installed. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [instructions you followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration) it mentions that as of Windows 10 October 18 Windows Hypervisor Platform is enabled by default:

> On Windows 10 October 2018 Update (RS5) and higher, you only need to enable Hyper-V, as it will use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) automatically.

You should therefore uncheck it from Windows Features it will be enabled for you.

Comment: Thanks. Shows how you need to read the instructions carefully! Mind you, it wasn't clear that enabling something which will be enabled for me would break it 